# check if this group theory problem is correct?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be any group and let $g\in G$ have order $mn$ where $gcd(m,n)=1$. Prove that there is some power $g^k$ so that the order of $g^k$ is $m$ and the order of $g^{k-1}$ is n.

I think there is something wrong with this problem as I'm checking some finite groups and cannot find such $g^k$

Comment: $\Bbb Z / mn$ is an example. (And everything reduces to it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need $(g^k)^m=1$ and $(g^{k-1})^n=1$. This implies $mn \mid km$ and $mn \mid (k-1)n$. Simplifying gives
$$
k \equiv 0 \bmod n, \quad k \equiv 1 \bmod m
$$
Let $am+bn=1$. Then $k \equiv 1\cdot bn + 0 \cdot am \bmod mn$ and so $k=bn$ should work.

Indeed, with $k=bn$ we get
$$
o(g^k) = \frac{mn}{(bn,mn)} = \frac{m}{(b,m)} = m
$$
$$
o(g^{k-1}) = \frac{mn}{(-am,mn)} = \frac{n}{(-a,n)} = n
$$
because $am+bn=1$ implies $(b,m)=1$ and $(-a,n)=1$.